# How to resolve "Flutter.framework: code object is not signed at all"?

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, dart, app-store

I have been facing big time trouble uploading my iOS version of flutter app archive to App Store. I am having no issues in `flutter build ios -v` & then creating the Archive from `Runner.xcworkspace` XCode project.

But when i am trying to upload to App Store from XCode Organizer, or Trying to Validate App, it shows:

[Code signing "Flutter.framework" failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhErd.png)

Distribution Logs (last few lines) from Xcode is:

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  Running /usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' 'D976031884AC762F726E0D6831549FB0CF987B92' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/entitlements~~~QEafFk' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework'

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework: replacing existing signature

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework: signed bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64) [org.cocoapods.FMDB]

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 0

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  Writing entitlements for <IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fa423112800; bundleID='io.flutter.flutter', path='<DVTFilePath:0x7fa425856a90:'/Users/jitu/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-05/Example 5-9-20 6.04 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'>', codeSigningInfo='<_DVTCodeSigningInformation_Path: 0x7fa425888a70; isSigned='1', isAdHocSigned='0', signingCertificate='<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fa4258fd130; name='Apple Development: John Doe (XX1234)', hash='D70315F96BBC6873073BA5930F96CE5258C18868', serialNumber='446C1E93619D5C94', certificateKinds='(
> "1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12",
> "1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2"
> ), issueDate='2020-09-04 02:07:07 +0000''>', entitlements='(null)', teamID='XX1234', identifier='io.flutter.flutter', executablePath='<DVTFilePath:0x7fa42586f590:'/Users/jitu/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-05/Example 5-9-20 6.04 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'>', hardenedRuntime='0'>'> to: /var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/entitlements~~~J7HU6I

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  Running /usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' 'D976031884AC762F726E0D6831549FB0CF987B92' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/entitlements~~~J7HU6I' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: replacing existing signature

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /var/folders/6h/f1j2jsyj49scfm4zvp707fg40000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~vNEvBQ/Root/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: code object is not signed at all

> 2020-09-05 07:44:51 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1

I am successfully running the same build in simulators, devices. I have tried cleaning by `flutter clean`, deleting `Pods` directory in `<project>/ios`, deleting `Podfile.lock` & also the `Runner.xcworkspace`

My current `Podfile.lock` looks like this:

```
PODS:
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - FMDB (2.7.5):
    - FMDB/standard (= 2.7.5)
  - FMDB/standard (2.7.5)
  - path_provider (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sqflite (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - FMDB (~> 2.7.2)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)
  - path_provider (from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`)
  - sqflite (from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - FMDB

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter
  path_provider:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios"
  sqflite:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Flutter: 0e3d915762c693b495b44d77113d4970485de6ec
  FMDB: 2ce00b547f966261cd18927a3ddb07cb6f3db82a
  path_provider: abfe2b5c733d04e238b0d8691db0cfd63a27a93c
  sqflite: 4001a31ff81d210346b500c55b17f4d6c7589dd0

PODFILE CHECKSUM: aafe91acc616949ddb318b77800a7f51bffa2a4c

COCOAPODS: 1.9.3
```